# Duplicate elements in query result set & InterfaceError: Error binding parameter

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I have the following DatabaseManager class which manages an SQLite database:

```
class DatabaseManager(object):
def __init__(self, db):
    self.conn = sqlite3.connect(db)
    self.conn.execute('pragma foreign_keys = on')
    self.conn.commit()
    self.cur = self.conn.cursor()
```

At one point in my application, I need to check whether a given article already exists in my database, and if it does, I want its `id`. I use the following method of the DatabaseManager:

```
def article_exists(self, url):
    self.cur.execute('SELECT id FROM articles WHERE url = ?', (url,))
    self.conn.commit()
    ids = list(self.cur)
    if len(ids) == 0:
        return (False, None)
    if len(ids) == 1:
        return (True, ids[0][0])
    else:
        print 'Duplicate articles:', url
        return (True, ids[0][0])
```

For some reason, in case the article already exists, the resulting `ids` list contains sometimes two elements with identical ids, e.g. `[(3,), (3,)]`. Do you know why this is happening?

I imagine I could just use `self.cur.fetchone()`; however, I find the behavior strange.

**UPDATE**

Table definition for `articles`:

```
CREATE TABLE articles (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    title TEXT,
    url TEXT,
    authors TEXT,
    abstract TEXT );
```

Whenever this problem happens, I also get the following error message:

> InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.

However, I also check the type of the variable `url` and it's always a string, which is the correct type.

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and `sys.version` gives:

```
2.7.3 (default, Feb 27 2014, 19:58:35) 
[GCC 4.6.3]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found what was causing the error message. After processing each article, I also update the `processed` flag - a column in the table of a related "message" object:

```
def set_processed(self, msgid):
    self.cur.execute('UPDATE messages SET processed=1 WHERE id = ?', (msgid,))
```

However, this method was missing the commit line:

```
self.conn.commit()
```

After adding it, everything works without any problems.

(However, if anyone can explain why this was happening, I'll be happy to know!)

Answer (score 0):

The only possible conclusion appears to be that you do indeed have duplicate entries in the database table. Since you don't show the table definition it's impossible to say how this arose, but it would appear that the `ID` column (which I presume is supposed to be the primary key) isn't uniquely indexed, thereby allowing duplicate values.

Comment: Thanks. I've added the the table definition. The `id` column is defined as `integer primary key`.

Comment: So it appears from your answer that it was a failure to commit that caused the initial problem. I'm sorry, I can't explain why you see duplicate values.